# Javascript showing popup message once but its showing every time the page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup

what i trying to do is the popup window show to user when he visite the page ONLY ONE TIME 
but its showing to me every time i refresh the page and also i need it not alert i need it popup Window

please advise

```
//Alert message once script- By JavaScript Kit
//Credit notice must stay intact for use
//Visit http://javascriptkit.com for this script

//specify message to alert
var alertmessage="Welcome to JavaScript Kit! \n http://javascriptkit.com"

///No editing required beyond here/////

//Alert only once per browser session (0=no, 1=yes)
var once_per_session=1


function get_cookie(Name) {
  var search = Name + "="
  var returnvalue = "";
  if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
    offset = document.cookie.indexOf(search)
    if (offset != -1) { // if cookie exists
      offset += search.length
      // set index of beginning of value
      end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", offset);
      // set index of end of cookie value
      if (end == -1)
         end = document.cookie.length;
      returnvalue=unescape(document.cookie.substring(offset, end))
      }
   }
  return returnvalue;
}

function alertornot(){
if (get_cookie('alerted')==''){
loadalert()
document.cookie="alerted=yes"
}
}

function loadalert(){
alert(alertmessage)
}

if (once_per_session==0)
loadalert()
else
alertornot()

</script>
```

Comment: Why not use localstorage?

Comment: i need it using cookie how i can do that

Comment: See the [execute once example #3](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie).

Answer (score 0):

How do you run your code?
If you are running it as a file in your browser from your local machine e.g

```
file://localhost/../../../file.html
```

you are not able to save a cookie from javascript.

You need to run your code on a webserver and access the code through that using http.

```
http://localhost/../../../file.html
```

w3schools has some very good examples:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

e.g

```
function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
 var d = new Date();
 d.setTime(d.getTime()+(exdays*24*60*60*1000));
 var expires = "expires="+d.toGMTString();
 document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}
```